# Maximization using Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

I am trying to come up with the solution for a problem analogous to the following:

- Let M be a matrix of n rows and T columns.
- Let each row have positive non-decreasing values. (e.g. row = [1, 2, 30, 30, 35])
- Let M[i][j] correspond to the score obtained by spending j units of time on exam i.

Using dynamic programming, solve the problem as to find the optimal way of spending T units of time to study which will yield the highest total score.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

My attempt:

```
S[][] = 0

for i = 1:n
   for j = 0:T
       max = 0
       for k = 0:j
           Grade = G[i][j]+ S[i-1][T-k]
           if Grade > max
              max = Grade
       end for
       S[i][j] = max
    end for
end for
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let `S[i][j]` represent the best score you can achieve spending `j` units of time on the first `i` exams.  You can calculate `S[i][j]` by looking at `S[i-1][k]` for each value of `k`.  For each element of `S`, remember the value of `k` from the previous row that gave the best result.  The answer to what the best score for studying all exams in time `T` is just `S[n][T]`, and you can use the values of `k` that you remembered to determine how much time to spend on each exam.

```
S[][] = 0

for j = 0:T
   S[0][j] = M[0][j]

for i = 1:n
   for j = 0:T
       max = 0
       for k = 0:j
           # This is the score you could get by spending j time, spending
           # k time on this exam and j-k time on the previous exams.
           Grade = S[i-1][j-k] + M[i][k]
           if Grade > max
              max = Grade
       end for
       S[i][j] = max
    end for
end for
```

Comment: Could you express this idea in the form a pseudo-code please? I have been trying to write something similar but I confuse myself and it leads me nowhere...

Comment: @Pi_: Could you add an example of what you have tried to your question?

Comment: @Pi_: I've added some pseudocode in a form similar to yours, which I believe works better.

Comment: I wrapped my head around it, thank you! (There's a tiny typo, it should be for j = 0:T).

Comment: @VaughnCato, `for i = 1:n` (where matrix indices are 0-based) does not iterate over a `n`-row matrix, but a `n+1`-row matrix. Idem with `for j = 0:T`, that's a `T+1` column matrix. :)

Comment: @vladr: True.  Perhaps the M matrix in the original question was intended to be a T+1 column matrix.

Comment: "calculate S[i][j] by looking at S[i-1][k]" did you mean by looking at S[i-1][j-k] instead?

Comment: Also can you better explain how to "remember" the value of k and reconstruct the best allocation of hours for each class?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that vy G and M in your problem you mean the same thing, and that you get 0 score if you do not spend any time at all for an exam.

In this case, I would define the DP matrix as D[i,t] = best score achievable by spending t total units of times on a subset of the exams from 0 to i.

W.l.o.g. you can assume the first column of the matrix to be all 0s.

In this case, you can observe that D satisfies the following recurrence:

- D[0, t] = M[0, t]
- D[i, t] = max_{0 <= k <= t} (M[i, k] + D[i-1, t-k])

which is what you need to apply dynamic programming